# Division of very large numbers

Tags: c++, time-complexity, computation

I have written following code in C++:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double sum, containers, n ,c, max_cap, temp;

    unsigned int j = 1;
       cin >> n >> c;
       sum = containers = n;


       for (unsigned int i = 2 ; i <= c; ++i)
       {
           max_cap = i * n;

           if (max_cap - sum > 0)
           {
              temp = ceil((max_cap - sum)/i);
              containers += temp;
              sum += i * temp;
           }
       }

       cout << containers << '\n';
}
```

When the input given to this code is "728 1287644555" it takes about 5 seconds to compute the answer but when the input is roughly three times i.e. "763 3560664427" it is not giving a long time.(I waited for around half hour) As it can be seen the algo is of linear order. Therefore, it should take roughly 15 seconds. Why is this happening? Is it because the input is too large in second case? If yes then how is it affecting time so much?

Comment: `unsigned double`?

Comment: This is definitely **not** a valid C++ source code, not only because of `unsigned double` but also because of `continue` out of a loop. Could you provide a valid variant?

Comment: Apart from other issues already raised, your problem likely involves discrepancies between the range of valid `unsigned int`s (likely of the 32 bit variety given the numbers you quoted) and valid `double`s (64 bits). Hence the `unsigned int` may overflow and become `0` before the loop has a chance to terminate (due to `i <= c`) because the given `c` exceeds what can be represented in `i` before its promotion to double. Thus if `c >= UINT_MAX` the loop will continue spinning indefinitely.

Comment: Output e.g. the value of `i` in the loop to get an insight. Also, you absolutely must learn how to use a debugger, which allows you to step through the code and examine variables.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be unsigned integer overflow.

```
       for (unsigned int i = 2 ; i <= c; ++i)
```

`i` increases until it is > `c`, but `c` is a double whereas `i` is an unsigned int. It reaches the maximum (`UINT_MAX`) and wraps to 0 before it reaches the value of `c`.

I.e. 1287644555 is less than `UINT_MAX`, so it completes. But 3560664427 is greater than `UINT_MAX`, so it loops forever. Which only raises the question of what strange architecture you are running this on :)

On my own machine (`UINT_MAX` = 4294967295) the first input takes 16 seconds to process while the second takes 43.5 seconds, pretty much what you'd expect.